# How get specific word from the file using batch scripting?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have a file of which the contents are as follows which are in consecutive lines,

```
VERSION=7.0.2
BUILD=03bbabbd5c0f
PRODUCT=splunk
PLATFORM=Windows-AMD64
```

From this I only want the VERSION. I tried using the following command:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1 eol=P" %G IN ("C:\ProgramFiles\SplunkUniversalForwarder\etc\splunk.version") DO echo %G
```

Involved `eol=P` because it doesn't bring out the last two lines, but I don't want the second line too. Can anyone help? Actually the main goal is to get only the version number not even the "VERSION=".

Comment: Use `Tokens=1* Delims==`, and `If /I "%G"=="VERSION"`, `%H` should be `7.0.2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpler:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %G IN ('findstr "VERSION" "C:\ProgramFiles\SplunkUniversalForwarder\etc\splunk.version"') DO echo %G
```

Use `findstr` command to select the desired line, that may be at *any position* in the file...

Comment: Great this worked , although i had earlier tried `findstr` but without the `delims==` and `tokens=2`, care to explain? Because as much i know the `version=7.0.2` is one whole word and how tokens=2 is working on it? Also delims==?

Comment: Are you asking how the token #2 works when the delimiter is a `=` on `version=7.0.2` string?  Really? **`:/`**

Comment: Well figured it out later, and yes i was asking about this as i am new to scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of my comment.

At the Command Prompt:

```dos
For /F "UseBackQ EOL=P Tokens=1* Delims==" %A In ("%ProgramFiles%\SplunkUniversalForwarder\etc\splunk.version") Do @Echo %B
```

As a batch file:

```dos
For /F "UseBackQ EOL=P Tokens=1* Delims==" %%A In ("%ProgramFiles%\SplunkUniversalForwarder\etc\splunk.version") Do @Echo %%B
```

Comment: Ok, this statement fetches the version details along with the Build number, which i don't want.

Answer (score 0):

In a batch file use this code:

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims==" %%A in ("C:\Program Files\SplunkUniversalForwarder\etc\splunk.version") do if /I "%%~A" == "VERSION" if not "%%~B" == "" set "Version=%%~B" & goto HaveVersion
echo Error: Could not find VERSION= with a version string in file:
echo        C:\Program Files\SplunkUniversalForwarder\etc\splunk.version
pause
goto :EOF

:HaveVersion
echo Version is: %Version%
pause
```

Please note the space in `Program Files`.

The command **FOR** with the used option `/F` reads the specified file line by line with skipping empty lines and lines starting with `;` which is the default for `eol` (end of line) option.

The option `usebackq` is required to get the full qualified file name enclosed in double quotes interpreted as file name and not as string to process. The double quotes `"` around full qualified file name are required because of space character.

`delims==` redefines the delimiters for splitting the lines into substrings (tokens) from default space and horizontal tab to equal sign. So **FOR** splits now the lines using only `=` as delimiter character for the strings.

`tokens=1*` means that the first equal sign delimited substring should be assigned to loop variable `A`. And the rest of the line after the first equal sign(s) should be assigned without any further splitting to next loop variable according to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) which is in this case the loop variable `B`. Now it should be also clear why loop variables are case-sensitive while environment variables are not case-sensitive. It makes a difference on what is the next loop variable if the specified loop variable is `A` or `a`.

On each loop run first a case-insensitive string comparison is made to check if the version string is at beginning of current line. If this first condition is true a second **IF** condition is used to verify that there is really a version string right to the equal sign in the file. If this second condition is also true the version string is assigned to environment variable `Version` and the loop is exited by continuing the batch file processing with a jump to the line below label `HaveVersion`. So the other lines in file are not further processed by **FOR**.

In general it is better to reference the environment variable `ProgramFiles` with `%ProgramFiles%` instead of using `C:\Program Files` as the standard program files directory for 64-bit applications on Windows x64 respectively for 32-bit applications on Windows x86 can be on any drive with any folder name. But the [Windows WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details) must be taken into account if the batch file should work on 32-bit Windows, on 64-bit Windows in 64-bit environment and on 64-bit Windows in 32-bit environment. See also Wikipedia article about [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows).

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`

See also [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of operator `&`.